# Yet another STL tree

Tags: list, dictionary, tree, stl

Quite a funny question I have.

I am working now on the HTML parser and I was using vector `<HTMLTag>` for all my input purposes which seemed quite fine and fast for creating tree.

In another application I need to edit HTML structure and now inserting or reordering of the elements would be extremely painful using vector so I decided to switch to more tree-like structure.

I read a few articles on trees and their implementation and I was thinking of std::map for this purpose.

Something like this:

`std::map< element, *child_map >`

So when I thought of inserting a tag somewhere in between and having them all ordered by some key (e.g. unique integer id) I still have a problem to update all keys in a branch after insertion.

for example:

```
1:SCRIPT
2:HEAD
3:BODY
```

When I want to insert new element "SCRIPT" after the HEAD I will need to increment Body Key to 4 and have something like this:

```
1:SCRIPT
2:HEAD
3:SCRIPT
4:BODY
```

Seems a bit cumbersome to me. Am I missing something?

As an alternative I thought of doing `list<pair<>>` implementation instead. Thus sorting is not determined by a key and I can add elements anywhere without any extra updates.

Comment: Clarify please what exactly you want to store in the map's key? Order of tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the child set a member of the element and use std::list:

```
class Element {
/* ... */
  std::list<boost::shared_ptr<Element> > children;
/* ... */
};
```

That said, you might want to look into using an existing DOM library instead of rolling your own. For example, you could use [htmlcxx](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: a list of Element * is a bit harder to clean up (you need to manually delete the children in the destructor or elsewhere) and makes ownership more complex when detaching Elements from their parents. I'd highly recommend using a smart pointer of some sort for this kind of case.

Comment: Thanks. Great idea! It is exactly what I needed. Actually, I was just writing almost identical implementation just before I found your reply.

Comment: one more question. If I want to provide feedback from child to parent, would it be a good idea to include std::week_ptr reference to a parent?

Answer (score 0):

List< pair > would work well to simulate any form of tree structure such as what you're trying to do:

list< pair< "html", list > would let you store an arbitrary number of children as well as control the order of objects in the child list.

Have fun walking this tree.